# Prevent text from suddenly moving when contents are changed with text-align: center

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  fade();

});


var fade = function() {

  $(".quotes").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $(this).text("World")
  }).fadeIn(2000);

};
```

```css
.iam {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
}

#aligned {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.quotes {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aligned">
  <h2 class="iam">I am</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
</div>
```

As you can see the text "I am" jumps after the function change the text, 
because of the text align center of the div.

How can I make this movement like a slow transition and not an istant jump?

Comment: Really interesting! Will work on this.

Answer (score 3):

Aha!

Here's a very hacky trick.
Put the element to be centered inside a wrapper div. Then, while fading, force it's width to remain the same. Now while fading it back in, animate the width to the width of the new text.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojas_gulati/aodjgdhf/12/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  fade()
});

var fade = function() {
  $(".wrapper").css("width", $(".quotes").width() + "px")
  $(".quotes").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    $(this).text("World")

    $(".quotes").fadeIn(2000)
    $(".wrapper").animate({
      width: $(".quotes").width() + "px"
    }, 2000)

  })

};
```

```css
.iam {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
}

#aligned {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aligned">
  <h2 class="iam">I am</h2>
  <h2 class="wrapper"><span class="quotes">first quote</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: but you added an extra markup ;) and the animation is somehow more complicated but nice one

Answer (score 1):

This is a gnarly one since I don't think that you can animate the `text-align` CSS property. A workaround would be using margin-auto instead where you set a `width` of `100%` to the container div `aligned` with an arbitrary `max-width` (this being the only caveat). See fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/aodjgdhf/9/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
   fade();

});


var fade = function () {

    $(".quotes").fadeOut(2000, function() {
      $(this).text("World")
     }).fadeIn(2000);     
};
```

```css
.iam{
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;

}

#aligned{
    width: 100%;
 max-width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto 5% ;
}

.quotes {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aligned">
 <h2 class="iam">I am</h2>
 <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: I did it without changing the text-align! (direct translation: I'm very proud of my answer so go and upvote it's a neat solution :D)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that doesn't involve a lot of changes and can be generic. The idea is to animate `opacity` and `max-width` at the same time. Simply make sure the value of max-width is enough big for the text you are using.

```js
var i=0;
var txt=["world","another text","first quote","lorem ipsum"]

var fade = function() {
  $(".quotes").animate({opacity:0,maxWidth:0},2000, function() {
    $(this).text(txt[i]);
  }).animate({opacity:1,maxWidth:180},2000);

};

$(document).ready(function() {
fade();
setInterval(function(){ 
  fade(); 
  i=(i+1)%4;
 
}, 5000);
});
```

```css
.iam {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
}

#aligned {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.quotes {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 180px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aligned">
  <h2 class="iam">I am</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By playing a bit with the margins, and using jQuery's animate, you can code the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".quotes").fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(".quotes").css("margin-right", "40px");
      $(".quotes").text("World");
    });

    $(".iam").animate({
      left: '12px'
    }, 2000);

    $(".quotes").fadeIn(1000);
  }, 1000);

});
```

```css
.iam {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

#aligned {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.quotes {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aligned">
  <h2 class="iam">I am</h2>
  <h2 class="quotes">first quote</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: but i don't think this will be a generic solution, as your valu will depend on the text